# Difference between PID and TID

Tags: linux, pid

What is the difference between PID and TID?

The standard answer would be that PID is for processes while TID is for threads. However, I have seen that some commands use them interchangeably. For example, `htop` has a column for PIDs, in which PIDs for threads of the same process are shown (with different values). So when does a PID represent a thread or a process?

Comment: You can change htop settings to view processes and threads in a different color. It also helps to use the Tree view.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It is complicated: *pid* is process identifier; *tid* is thread identifier.

But as it happens, the kernel doesn't make a real distinction between them: threads are just like processes but they share some things (memory, fds...) with other instances of the same *group*.

So, a *tid* is actually the identifier of the schedulable object in the kernel (thread), while the *pid* is the identifier of the group of schedulable objects that share memory and fds (process).

But to make things more interesting, when a process has only one thread (the initial situation and in the good old times the only one) the *pid* and the *tid* are always the same. So any function that works with a *tid* will automatically work with a *pid*.

It is worth noting that many functions/system calls/command line utilities documented to work with *pid* actually use *tids*. But if the effect is process-wide you will simply not notice the difference.

Comment: And to make it even more interesting: there is also the name *tgid* (thread group identifier) appearing in sources — you can already guess it is synonymous with *pid*.

Comment: *tid* from gettid() is not the same as pthread_t *tid*, See `man gettid`

Comment: What is the meaning of "fds" as used in this answer?

Comment: @Stephen _fds_ stands for _file descriptors_, that is, those small integers that represent open files, sockets or similar objects.

Comment: A simple question: can [taskset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) be used with TID instead of PID? Actually a bit confused: man says: "set or retrieve a _process's_ CPU affinity", and then "The success of the command does not guarantee that the specified _thread_ has actually migrated to the indicated CPU(s), but only that the _thread_ will not migrate to a CPU outside the new affinity mask."

Comment: @pmor: Well, you can test it... and indeed it works! It looks like it is one of these cases that they say PID when they mean TID. In fact, there is the command option `--all-tasks` that it says: _Set or retrieve the CPU affinity of all the tasks (threads) for a given PID._. And if you try it with a threaded program you'll see that it just loops through all the TIDs of that thread-group (i.e. whole process).

Comment: @rodrigo Just to confirm: does Linux kernel guarantee that PID and TID don't overlap (at any time tick)?

Comment: @pmor: As I understand it the PID is actually the "task group id", that matches with the TID of the leading thread. In a single-thread process its PID and TID are one and the same, in a multi-thread process, the PID is the TID of the _main_ thread... does this count as an overlap? I guess it depends on the point of view...

Answer (score 5):

Actually, each thread in a Linux process is Light Weight Process (LWP). So, people may call thread as a process... But there is surely a difference.
Each thread in a process has a different thread ID (TID) and share the same process ID (PID).

If you are working with pthread library functions, then these functions don't use these TIDs because these are kernel/OS level thread IDs.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to other answers, according to `man gettid`:

> *The  thread  ID  returned  by  this  call  is  not  the  same  thing  as a POSIX thread ID (i.e., the opaque value returned by pthread_self(3)).*

So there are two different things one could mean by TID!

Answer (score 1):

pid and tid are the same except when a process is created with a call to `clone` with `CLONE_THREAD` (per the man pages of `gettid`). In this case, you get a unique thread id but all threads belonging to the same thread group share the same process id.

However, I also recall reading (though I cant find the source) that the values returned from `getpid` may be cached.

[UPDATE]
See the `NOTES` section [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getpid.2.html) for a discussion on the effects of caching `pids`.